# continuity of function and usual topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How to prove that $h(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology ?

I must prove that $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, |x-x_0|\leq\delta\Rightarrow |\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x_0^2}|\leq \varepsilon$

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and i must find $\delta$

$$ |\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x_0^2}|=|\frac{x_0^2-x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+x_0^2)}|=|\frac{(x_0+x)(x_0-x)}{(1+x^2)(1+x_0^2)}|=\frac{|x_0+x||x_0-x|}{|(1+x^2)(1+x_0^2)|}$$

But i dont know how to continue

Thank you

Comment: As well as the two posts below, you might also like to look at this http://people.bath.ac.uk/sej20/docs/epsilondelta.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{|x_0+x||x_0-x|}{|(1+x^2)(1+x_0^2)|} \leq |x_0+x||x_0-x|$$

Comment: ok, so $|x_0+x||x_0-x|\leq \varepsilon$ how we choose $\delta$ please

Comment: @Vrouvrou Think about it for a second.

Comment: $|x + x_0| = |x - x_0 + 2x_0| \le |x - x_0| + 2|x_0| < \delta + 2|x_0|$.

Comment: @Unit Actually, you can even just say $\delta<|x_0|$ which makes $|x+x_0|<2|x_0|.$ But the idea was that OP should figure that out by himself...

Comment: I take $\delta<\min(\displaystyle\frac{|x_0|}{2},\displaystyle\frac{2\varepsilon}{5|x_0|})$ right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Looks about right...

Comment: @5xum please can we say that $h$ is not open because $h(]-1,1[)=\{\frac12\}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou What is $h$? What do you mean by "not open"? Your comment makes no sense...

Comment: $h$ is the function witch is continuous, i say that it s open if the image of an open by the function is open

Comment: @Vrouvrou And what is $|-1,1|$?

Comment: not $|-1,1|$ but $]-1,1[$

Comment: @Vrouvrou but $h(]-1,1[)$ is not $\{\frac12\}$. $h(0)$, for example, is $1$.

Comment: so how to prove that $h$ is not open ? thank you

Comment: @5xum please i need an open from the usual topology such that it's image by $h$ is not open

Comment: @Vrouvrou First, calculate what $h(]-1,1[)$ is.

Comment: $= ]\frac12,1]$

Comment: @Vrouvrou And is that an open set?

Comment: No, so my application is not open

Comment: @Vrouvrou There you go. You did it. Consider accepting this answer since it obviously helped you...

Answer (score 0):

you might know that $1+x^2 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_{>0}$ and $ \frac 1z : \mathbb R_{>0} \to \mathbb R $ are continous. If you know that compositions of continous functions is continous, you are done.